# Simple trig question.

Tags: trigonometry

There exists an isosceles triangle. The sides are 6, 6, and 8. I am to find what all of the angles equal. My method to do this was to split the triangle in half giving me a right triangle where side a=4, using Pythagoras theorem I found side b= square root of 20, and where c= 6......

Thus at random I chose an angle to be theta and did the function, Cosine of theta is equal to the square root of twenty over six, giving me 0.75. However, this isn't a degree measure is it? it is too small. Furthermore I tried another function where the sine of theta equals four divided by 6, and got the answer (2/3). Thus the two answers do not line up as they should. This is probably really simple, but I need help. Please note this is not a question about the acutal answer to the problem, but a question about the error in my methods of using trig functions. Thank you

Comment: You don't even need to create right triangles, since you can just use the Law of Cosines on the isosceles triangle to get one angle and then Law of Sines to get the other two angles.

Comment: How do you get $0.75$ and $\frac23$? For me, $$ \arccos(\frac{\sqrt{20}}6) = \arcsin(\frac46) =  0.729727656... = 41.8103^\circ$$

Comment: @onetoinfinity: I think splitting into two equal right triangles is plenty simpler than using the law of cosines. And certainly the law of sines is overkill once you know one angle: since the triangle is isoscles, knowing that the angle sum must be $\pi$ suffices to find all angles from one.

Comment: @HenningMakholm yeah there are better ways, but that's a general solution that will work with any triangle given the sides. I should have pointed that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Base angle

The base angle of your triangle is $\theta$ and what you know is that $\cos(\theta)=\frac{4}{6}=\frac{2}{3}$.  So, to get $\theta$ use an inverse function $\theta=\cos^{-1}(\frac{2}{3})$.  Be careful to make sure your angle is in degrees not radians.

Other angles:

The same procedure can be used on the other angles.  In the example you gave, you had $\cos(\theta)=\frac{\sqrt{20}}{6}$, then $\theta=\cos^{-1}(\frac{\sqrt{20}}{6})$.

Note, this angle can also be obtained by noting that the sum of the angles in any triangle is 180, and you already have a base angle (count it twice since the two base angles are the same) and deduce the third angle (in your isosceles triangle).  The angle in the right triangle is half this angle.

Comment: The $\theta$ the OP is actually finding is half the apex angle, not the base angle.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, I used $\theta$ as a generic angle for the base angle... I should've been more careful to not recycle the OP's notation.